# transparent overlay over image

Tags: 3d-view, video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes, transparency

The effect i want achieve looks like this where there's an image moving in space with particles (dust, grain, dirt, scratches) moving over them.

The Video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=altvY5rt6oc

You can see the effect in action here in this video at 0:40-0:49. 
[image: Scratches overlay]

So far I've got stock footage of dust particles but I don't know how to find out if it has an alpha channel and whether one is needed to achieve the effect?

[image: Dust particle footage]

I believe I would set up the scene in the 3D view and then overlay the footage over my images using the compositor. But as i'm still fairly new to the compositor i'm not sure if it's possible and was wondering if anyone knew how to achieve the effect?

I'll experiment and put down what my experimentation with the compositor results in later on today.

I'll probably ask another question on how to achieve the image distortion thats used as well which ill link to this question.

Many thanks to anyone who helps me out.

Comment: Would the effect be achievable if I found a stock footage of dust with a transparent background ?

Comment: Also what does smashed by Z axis mean?

Comment: The effect will be achievable if you find any photo of desired particles on transparent background. However I don't think it's efficient way to do that as it is often created within Blender as is stated in linked answers. As to "smashed" may be my wording wasn't good, I meant the vertical blurred lines on top of image.

Comment: @User33287 are you looking to animate this dust overlay or just have it sitting 'suspended' on the background image/movie? I've made a Blender file for an earlier project that produces an image sequence (video) of animated 'dust' particles (much as you've shown above)  on a transparent alpha layer, explicitly for overlaying backgrounds, video and still. Can upload if you wish. As it's set up, it produces 500 frames to choose from should you only need a single frame to texture a plane or use in the VSE

Comment: @Edgel3D I was hoping to have the dust overlay animated over the background image/movie. Uploading that would be a great help as I should be able to get a grasp of the process of how it's done, but I may still have specific questions though

Comment: @User33287, it's midnight here and I can't face having to write up a proper answer in order to dump up the Blend file.  Leave me that anonymous email address and I'll email it and the dust particle overlays already rendered, across.

Comment: @Edgel3D moreemailsmore@gmail.com
cheers, I've tried The Lie's method and it works just fine but I'd still like to still see your method as the Inviso Mask is really innovative and functional- so thanks a lot!

Comment: It;s just a particle emitter, nothing magical.  I'm awake now, lol.  I'll drop it up here as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested the Blend file I used some time back has been placed here.

[image]

It's nothing more than a particle emitter with very few particles over a very long time - typically 50 particles over 1000 frames, their lifetime also 1000.

Physics settings were typically with a Size of 0.05, Brownian of 12.68, Damping of 0.224 .

The resultant alpha layered output (single frame .png files) can be an overlay for a video or image.  They can also be adjusted for further visual effects in the compositor or VSE as one would any image or material.

Don't forget to nominate your own folder for the video output -
there'll be 1000 files going somewhere if you don't !

Glad you've got your project going as things are...

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Solution for at least the overlay of your stock effect over the images:

[image]

As you can see, I used a color key to get rid of the black in the overlay image and added the overlay and background image via Alpha over.

Comment: Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for blend uploads which is a more permanent file host for this site. Also, preferably files should be supplemental to your answer, so please include screenshots and any relevant explanation in the answer body itself.

Comment: Cheers for the speedy response! Just wondering would this method work with an animation? Would I have to input it as an image sequence in the image bode?

Comment: Apologies @The lie, clicked on the wrong comment button!

Comment: @user33287 You'd use Input > Movie Clip for That.